# Julia function result changes every shift-enter

Tags: julia, integration

I'm trying to create a trapezoidal function numerical method in Julia. I've written the code but I need to hit shift-enter two times to get desired result.

```
f(x)=(x+(2/x)^2

a=1
b=0
s=0.5*(f(a)+f(b))
n = 1
h=(b-a)/n

for i = 1 : n-1
s = s + f(a+(i*h))
end

I = h*s
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This code is not working. Also you should wrap your logic inside a function, or it will not work properly (unless you are in Jupyter Notebook, which I guess you use). The problem is that variable `s` is in global scope and it will not be visible inside the loop if you run your code from REPL or as a script.

Here is the proper code:

```
function I(f, a, b, n)
    s=0.5*(f(a)+f(b))
    h=(b-a)/n
    for i = 1 : n-1
        s = s + f(a+(i*h))
    end
    h*s
end
```

and how you can use it:

```
julia> f(x)=x^4
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a=0
0

julia> b=1
1

julia> n=100
100

julia> I(f, a, b, n)
0.20003333300000006
```